# Get XMLType from a cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

Anyone knows if I can generate a XMLType from a cursor without having to specify each row's name manually ?

I would like to be able to loop over my query, and to get a separate XML for each row.

I couldn't get a solution using DBMS_XMLGEN.getXMLType, but perhaps I didn't use it properly.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "MY_SCHEMA"."TEST" AS

CURSOR mySelectCursor is
    SELECT '1a' as "column1", '1b' as "column2" FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2a' as "column1", '2b' as "column2" FROM DUAL;

myXMLType XMLType;
BEGIN

FOR mySelect in mySelectCursor
    LOOP
        -- I would like to replace the following line of code
        myXMLType := XMLType('<row><column1>' || mySelect."column1" || '</column1><column2>' || mySelect."column2" || '</column2></row>');
        -- by something similar to this (not working) one
        --myXMLType := mySelect.getXMLType();
        dbms_output.put_line(myXMLType.getClobVal());
    END LOOP;
END;

--The following code outputs
--<row><column1>1a</column1><column2>1b</column2></row>
--<row><column1>2a</column1><column2>2b</column2></row>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution with XMLTABLE rather than XMLSEQUENCE.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "MY_SCHEMA"."TEST" AS

CURSOR mySelectCursor IS
    SELECT 
        VALUE(table_temp) AS "XMLTYPE"
    FROM 
        XMLTABLE('/ROWSET/ROW' PASSING 
            DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXMLTYPE('
                SELECT ''1a'' as "column1", ''1b'' as "column2" FROM DUAL
                UNION ALL
                SELECT ''2a'' as "column1", ''2b'' as "column2" FROM DUAL
            ')
        ) table_temp;
BEGIN

FOR mySelect IN mySelectCursor
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(mySelect."XMLTYPE".getClobVal());
    END LOOP;
END;

-- Output is :

--<ROW><column1>1a</column1><column2>1b</column2></ROW>
--<ROW><column1>2a</column1><column2>2b</column2></ROW>
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally have found a solution.

Thank you for your help.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "MY_SCHEMA"."TEST" AS

CURSOR mySelectCursor is
    SELECT 
        VALUE(table_temp) as "XMLTYPE"
    FROM 
        table(
            XMLSequence(
                Cursor(
                    SELECT '1a' as "column1", '1b' as "column2" FROM DUAL
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT '2a' as "column1", '2b' as "column2" FROM DUAL
                )
            )
        ) table_temp;

BEGIN

FOR mySelect in mySelectCursor
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('===');
        dbms_output.put_line(mySelect."XMLTYPE".getClobVal());
    END LOOP;
END;


-- Output is :

--===
-- <ROW>
--  <column1>1a</column1>
--  <column2>1b</column2>
-- </ROW>
--
--===
-- <ROW>
--  <column1>2a</column1>
--  <column2>2b</column2>
-- </ROW>
```

Comment: Do not use XMLSEQUENCE, it is deprecated.

Comment: How can I change XMLSequence by XMLTABLE on this query ?

Comment: If your requirement is to loop through then see my answer which uses SYS_XMLAGG and SYS_XMLGEN

Comment: The problem with that solution is that I don't want to use an extra type (test_type).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet, you need to use DBMS_XMLGEN.getxml:

```
DECLARE
  v_xml   CLOB;
  v_more  BOOLEAN := TRUE;
BEGIN
  v_xml := DBMS_XMLGEN.getxml('select * from dual');
  dbms_output.put_line(v_xml);
END;
/
```

Here is the code snippet, to loop in a cursor

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE test_type AS OBJECT (
  col1 CHAR(2),
  col2 CHAR(2)
);
/

create or replace view test_view
as SELECT '1a' as column1, '1b' as column2 FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2a' as column1, '2b' as column2 FROM DUAL;

DECLARE
  CURSOR c_xml IS
     SELECT SYS_XMLAGG(
              SYS_XMLGEN(
                 test_type(column1, column2),
                 sys.xmlgenformatType.createFormat('TABLE')
              ),
              sys.xmlgenformatType.createFormat('TEST_VIEW')
            ).getStringVal() AS xml_row
     FROM test_view;
BEGIN
    FOR cur_rec IN c_xml LOOP
 dbms_output.put_line(cur_rec.xml_row);
    END LOOP;
 end;
/
```

Comment: Don't forget I would like to loop over my query, and get a separate xml for each row.

Comment: @fop6316 - added code snippet to loop through cursor as well. You need to use sys_xmlagg and sys_xmlgen.

Answer (score 0):

Does this query fit you needs:

```
WITH t AS
    (SELECT '1a' AS c1, '1b' AS c2 FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2a' AS c1, '2b' AS c2 FROM DUAL)
SELECT XMLELEMENT("row", 
           XMLELEMENT("column1", c1 ), 
           XMLELEMENT("column2", c2 )
       ) AS myXMLType
FROM t;
```

Another way would be this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "row" AS OBJECT (
 "column1" VARCHAR2(100),
 "column2" VARCHAR2(100))
/

WITH t AS
    (SELECT '1a' AS c1, '1b' AS c2 FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2a' AS c1, '2b' AS c2 FROM DUAL)
SELECT XMLTYPE("row"(c1,c2)) AS myXMLType
FROM t;
```